Get files from Clipboard, copied from the local machine in a remote session in VBA
In a RDP session using MS Access VBA, getting file paths from the clipboard with format CF_HDROP is not working when the files in the clipboard are copied from the local machine.
I can successfully use the solution described here on locally copied files:
VBA: Read file from clipboard
But it does not work if the files in the clipboard are from the local machine and I'm reading the clipboard in a remote desktop. The function is exiting on the line:
If Not CBool(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP)) Then Exit Function

I'm suspecting the files are not in CF_HDROP format when copied from the local machine. I can paste the files in Windows Explorer, so I know they are actually in the clipboard.

As far as I know, remote files are handled using virtual folders, see the WinAPI docs on accepting data from a virtual folder. This means you need to rewrite that code substantially to accept these files (as well as files from the recycle bin, for example).

@ErikA Thank you. I will look into this further!

@HenrikLamme you can use EnumClipboardFormats() to see what formats are actually on the clipboard.
